# validate xml with xsd schema with attribute xmlns

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a problem when you go to validate my xml with xsd schema, I assume that is the xmlns attribute, in my tests throws me the following error:

"The {name} of an attribute declaration must not match 'xmlns'."

My xsd schema:

```
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MensajeProv">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Datos">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <xs:element name="Mensaje">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:element name="tipoMsjID" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="proveedorID" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="usuario" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="fechaIni" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="fechaFin" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="empresaID" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="tipoID" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="tituloMsj" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="descripcionMsj" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="URL" type="xs:anyURI" />
                    <xs:element name="accionURL" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Firmante">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <xs:element name="Fecha" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="sistemaID" type="xs:int" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Signature" >
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <xs:element name="SignedInfo">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:element name="CanonicalizationMethod" />
                    <xs:element name="Reference">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Transforms">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name ="Transform" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="DigestMethod"/>
                          <xs:element name="DigestValue" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="SignatureValue" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="Signature">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CanonicalizationMethod">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="SignatureMethod">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Reference">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="URI" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Transform">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DigestMethod">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A guess, but your complexType Signature has an attribute called xmlns, rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, xmlns is like a reserved word, which is used only to declare a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
<xs:complexType name="Signature">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

It's illegal to have any attributes starting with the letters 'x', 'm', 'l'. So the name of the attribute 'xmlns' has to be changed.

Comment: We can't have attributes starting with 'xml'? Do you have an official W3C source for this statement?

Comment: [XML 1.0 W3C Recommendation: 3 Logical Structures](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-logical-struct)